# How can I extend a refrigerator water line?

Tags: water, refrigerator, hose, ice-maker

I had to purchase a new refrigerator, but of course the water inlet connection for the ice maker is on the opposite side and the 1/4" stainless steel braided compression line does not reach. The 10ft line is still like new, but buried behind my cabinets so replacing it with a longer line is not a practical option for me. I was wondering if there is a line like the one I have pictured below, but with 1 male end or if there is a fitting I can buy to join two lines like that together. I haven't had much luck in my searching. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It's a violation of plumbing codes to use any such flexible connector hose in non-accessible spaces.

Comment: Is the area behind a refrigerator considered inaccessible? I doubt it.

Comment: @kreemoweet as long as the fridge can be moved, it's not an inaccessible space.  Not like burying it inside a wall or something.

Comment: The water line is not completely inaccessible. I would just prefer not to. Its that I would have to empty out some cabinets, take drawers out and pull out the dishwasher. Just a PITA.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to get a fitting like this ([example](https://www.lowes.com/pd/B-K-1-4-in-Threaded-Male-Adapter-Nipple-Fitting/1000505625)):

[image: 1/4" M-M straight adapter]

Be sure to test fit at the store to make sure you have the correct thread profile. The BigBox store staff should probably be able to help you, but don't trust them 100%. Always try it before you buy it.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what I need

Comment: Accepting the answer is all the thanks I need.... Hope it works out for you.